# Riemann tensor with 2nd and last indice the same will vanish?

Tags: general-relativity, curvature, tensor-calculus

I calculated that Riemann tensors are antisymmetric with respect to 2nd and last indice,as the symmetry properities of $R_{\rho\nu\sigma\mu}$ goes.

$$R^{\omega}_{\ \ \ \nu\sigma\mu}=g^{\rho\omega}R_{\rho\nu\sigma\mu}=-g^{\rho\omega}R_{\rho\nu\mu\sigma}=-g^{\rho\omega}R_{\rho\mu\sigma\nu}=-R^{\omega}_{\ \ \ \mu\sigma\nu}$$
then for example
$$R^{\omega}_{\ \ \ x\sigma x}=-R^{\omega}_{\ \ \ x\sigma x}$$
therefore
$$R^{\omega}_{\ \ \ x\sigma x}=0$$

I'm sure they shouln't be zero, but why could the derivation like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your third equality. You want to have $R_{\rho\nu\mu\sigma} = R_{\rho\mu\sigma\nu}$. However, what the first Bianchi identity tells you is that
$$ R_{\rho\nu\mu\sigma} = -R_{\rho\mu\sigma\nu} - R_{\rho\sigma\nu\mu}. $$
I'm guessing you saw the Bianchi identity expressed as $R_{\rho[\nu\mu\sigma]} = 0$ and made the analogy with $T_{[\alpha\beta]} = 0 \Rightarrow T_{\alpha\beta} = T_{\beta\alpha}$. Unfortunately, this does not extend two three indices by interpreting the change of indices to be a cyclic one. That is, $T_{[\alpha\beta\gamma]} = 0 \not\Rightarrow T_{\alpha\beta\gamma} = T_{\beta\gamma\alpha}$.